# Reading a set of variables into a Makefile from a C source file?

Tags: c, makefile, avr

I have an AVR8 GCC application that can be built with a standard `makefile`.  Because some folks who want to build the application don't want to set up make and such (or have trouble doing so), I also have figured out how to set the project up so it can be compiled from the Arduino IDE as well.

All is working.

But, I normally set some items in the `makefile`, like the version number and such, but creating the VERSION string in the `makefile` and passing it as a define into each source file compilation.  But, when run from the Arduino IDE, that step is obviously not occurring.  So, I have to create a second `#define` in the Arduino sketch stub to recreate the define.

This means when I update the version, I need to do so in 2 places, in the `makefile` and in the source file.

The easy option is to simply move the `VERSION` creation to the source file, where both can use it.  And, I'm OK doing that, but

The `makefile` actually needs the version information, both to create the right filename (think **app_v1.2.3.4.bin**) and embed the version number into the bin file since it is used by the boot-loader (if requested) to ensure the version the boot-loader flashes is newer than the one already in FLASH.  So, if I move the `VERSION`, `RELEASE`, `MODIFICATION`, etc. defines into the C code, I need to find a way to pull them back into the `makefile`.

I tried using the file read operations in the `makefile`, but they seem to ignore:

```
#define VERSION 0
```

with the prefaced '#' char.

I see there's some options to run sed/awk/etc, in bash, but I don't want to make too many assumptions on the environment, and the `makefile` currently runs on Windows as well as Unix/Linux without any differences.

I tried a few stack overflow examples, but nothing seems to yield those 4 numbers from any file, .h or otherwise.

I'm OK with creating version.h with just:

```
#define VERSION      0
#define RELEASE      1
#define MODIFICATION 2
#define FIX          4
```

If I can read it into the `makefile` and create the variables I need.

Jim

Comment: Are you using GNU make or some other make?

Comment: I am using gnu make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which was designed exactly with you use case in mind. In `gmtt` the following should read and analyze your header file:

```
include gmtt.mk

# create a 3-column table from the header file. The first column is just the "#define"
VNR_TABLE := 3 $(file < version.h)

# Extract the values from the table: select column 3 from VNR_TABLE where column 2 equals a string constant. 
# Be careful not to introduce spaces in the compare!
VER := $(call select,3,$(VNR_TABLE),$$(call str-eq,$$2,VERSION))
REL := $(call select,3,$(VNR_TABLE),$$(call str-eq,$$2,RELEASE))
MODF := $(call select,3,$(VNR_TABLE),$$(call str-eq,$$2,MODIFICATION))
FIX := $(call select,3,$(VNR_TABLE),$$(call str-eq,$$2,FIX))
```

I couldn't test it but I think you get the idea.

PS: using a GNUmake library just means placing the `include`d file alongside the `makefile`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works just fine and does not resort to ugly shell hacking.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can use the ‘file’ function of makefiles.
It allows you to write (with > specifier) or read (with < specifier) to/from files. Then you can trim (with filter-out) your variables inside your makefile.
Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function

Comment: Re-reading your question, what make version are you using? file function only works with 4.2 and above

Comment: As I noted above in my question, I've already tried the file function `$(file < version.h)`, but if I don't have the '#' in the #define, make 4.3 spits out an error 'make: define: No such file or directory', and if I prepend the # in front of define, the lines appear to be ignored as comments.  I think the file function reads in the data as if it were Makefile commands, and so anything with has '#' in front might just be ignored as a comment.

Comment: the only workaround I can think of is using cat or type depending on the os

`cat := $(if $(filter $(OS),Windows_NT),type,cat)`
`variable := $(shell $(cat) filename)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU make's `$(shell ...)` function to extract the macro expansions. Assuming `VERSION` is defined in `src.c` and tokens are delimited by spaces (not tabs):

```
VERSION := $(shell sed -n -e "s/^\#define VERSION  *\(.*\)/\1/p" src.c)

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo VERSION=$(VERSION)
```

Comment: As noted in the original request, I'd prefer not to use shell, since there's no guarantee a full set of unix tools will be available.  I'd prefer to make as few tool pre-reqs as possible.