# Is it possible to pass variable value from source file to makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I want to for example pass value which i have in main.c.

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 1
#define VERSION_PATCH 0
```

That i can get these value in makefile variable for versiong my *.exe
For example then will my exe name look program_version_$(VERSION_MAJ)*$(VERSION_MIN)*$(VERSION_PAT).exe

Comment: No it's not generally possible (or rather kind of hard and complex), but the other way around is *very* easy. Perhaps you should do that instead?

Comment: Instead of messing around with such strange things, maybe start using actual version control? I don't quite see why the make file needs to know which version it is building. Rather, it could tell the program which version it is.

Comment: If you're using GNU make and have POSIX tools like `sed` etc. you can write a `$(shell ...)` function that uses shell operations to extract these values from the file.  It is true that it's simpler to put the values into the makefile and have the makefile write them to the source than the other way around, but it can be done either way if you have a decent shell environment.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840738/reading-a-set-of-variables-into-a-makefile-from-a-c-source-file/64860407#64860407

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but way too complicated and not the best idea.

The better approach is to define the version in the makefile and then define the macros on the compiler command line (with -D in gcc).

Comment: Can you give me some example ?

Comment: @hellboy Try something like `CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION_MAJOR=1` in your `Makefile`. Then how the `CPPFLAGS` variable is used in the `Makefile` depends on how much you use implicit rules.